# Keeping track of WHERE clause value that don't yield result

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a function that checks whether a given email address exists in a "user" table. I use sequelize's findone method to do that. This method is simple enough for finding particular value in the table. But, what I like to do is to keep track of those email addresses that aren't in that table. I'm not sure if there is any event that I can intercept for that matter. But my google attempts didn't yield any solution. So any help is appreciated. This is my code

```
function IsUserExist(email, callback)
{
    var userModel = sequelize.define('user', {
       email_address: Sequelize.STRING(255)             
    },
    { timestamps: false,
      freezeTableName: true 
    });

    userModel.findOne({
       where: { email_address: emailAddress }
    })
    .then(function(users){                         
       callback();
    })          
    .catch(function(err){
       console.log("Error while accessing user table");
    })
    .done();    
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'keep track of'? Do you want to keep a cache of those which don't exist so you can reply without checking the db if the query is executed again? 
Have a look at hooks, before and afterFind should help you http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/

Comment: Not for caching. I just want to run a check if the user have an account before creating a content on the remote system and save the list in a log file. But I finally figure out how to do it. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figure out how to do it. Basically, the parameter of "then" method is null if findOne does not yield any result. So, in my case "users" is null if a query does not return any result. If it does, "users" contains a record.